# How to sum values in array from different columns + EXCEL VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, excel

I need to calculate this in excel vba ,using array loop only :

```
round 0   round 1
9         28
65        84
28        47
84        103
41        60
66        85
115       134
```

I need to sum values in **round 0** in loop so the sum result (408) must be divided by 7 , **if not** I WANT to sum one value from the round 1 **(in this case 84 instead of 65 )** to the rest of values in **round 0** so the sum result can divided by 7 . There will be so many round up to 7 . I need VBA code to accomplish this..

Notes :
round 0 and round 1 all in one two-dimensional array
My Question is : is there a way to sum values from different columns in multi-dimensional array ??

there is an image attached .

I appreciate any help or idea .

Thanks in advance

Excel VBA Array Model:
http://im56.gulfup.com/8rDErI.png

Here an example file contains macro "Question1.xlsm"
http://www.gulfup.com/?TKAAYM

Notes : click the link under the big green down arrow to download the file.

UPDATE :
here another macro to the file "Question1.xlsm" :

```
Sub A1()

Dim arrTemp1() As Integer
Dim sum1 As Integer

arrblkTable1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("blkTable1").Value

ReDim Preserve arrTemp1(0 To 1, 1 To 7)
    For a = 0 To 1
        sum1 = 0
        For c = 1 To 7

                arrTemp1(a, c) = arrblkTable1(c, 1) + (a * 19)
                text6 = text6 & arrTemp1(a, c) & vbCrLf

                Worksheets("TEST3").Cells(a + 1, c).Value = arrTemp1(a, c)

                sum1 = sum1 + arrTemp1(a, c)


        Next c
        If XLMod(sum1, 7) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Yes  " & sum1
        Else
            MsgBox "No  " & sum1
        End If
    Next a
        MsgBox text6

End Sub

Function XLMod(a, b)
    ' This replicates the Excel MOD function
    XLMod = a - b * Int(a / b)
End Function
```

UPDATE : here a new update to the previous macro :

```
Sub A1()

Dim arrTemp1(), arrTemp2(), arrSUMs() As Integer
Dim sum1 As Integer

arrblkTable1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("blkTable1").Value
arrblkTable2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("blkTable2").Value

'-------------------------------- arrTemp1 ------------------------------

ReDim Preserve arrTemp1(0 To 1, 1 To 7)
    For a = 0 To 1
        sum1 = 0
        For c = 1 To 7
            arrTemp1(a, c) = arrblkTable1(c, 1) + (a * 19)
            text6 = text6 & arrTemp1(a, c) & vbCrLf
            Worksheets("TEST3").Cells(a + 1, c).Value = arrTemp1(a, c)
            sum1 = sum1 + arrTemp1(a, c)
        Next c
        If XLMod(sum1, 7) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Yes  " & sum1
        Else
            MsgBox "No  " & sum1
            For c = 1 To 7
                sum1 = sum1 - arrTemp1(a, c)
                arrTemp1(a, c) = arrblkTable1(c, 1) + ((a + 1) * 19)
                sum1 = sum1 + arrTemp1(a, c)
                If XLMod(sum1, 7) = 0 Then
                    MsgBox "Yes  " & sum1 & " " & arrTemp1(a, c)
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next a
    For x = 0 To UBound(arrTemp1)
        For y = 1 To UBound(arrTemp1)
            text7 = text7 & arrTemp1(x, y) & vbCrLf
        Next y
    Next x
    MsgBox text7
End Sub

Function XLMod(a, b)
    ' This replicates the Excel MOD function
    XLMod = a - b * Int(a / b)
End Function
```

I need now to put each sum1 in one array , how I can do that ??

Comment: Could you share with us what have you tried so far? so we can advise and troubleshoot

Comment: You're not looking to get an average of the values in column `round 0`, you're looking to get a set of numbers from that column, possibly a value with a value from `Round 1` such that it is evenly divisible by 7?

Comment: This code is part of bigger code , so unfortunately I couldn't share it so it will distribute you from the main Idea..
@FreeMan No I don't need the average .. I need in this case to sum 6 values from round 0 with 1 value from round 1 that accomplish the condition that is divided by 7

Comment: @KKowalczyk see the notes in the main post

Comment: @KKowalczyk there is an example file in the main post

Comment: @FreeMan there is an example file in the main post

Comment: @FreeMan see the UPDATE in the main post

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly you want something similar to this:

```
Sub p()

v = Range("A2:A8")
v1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B8")
s = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(v)
b = False

Count = 0
For i = 1 To 7


temp = v
temp(i, 1) = v1(i, 1)
s = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(temp)
b = s Mod 7 = 0

If b = True Then
Count = Count + 1
End If
Next

MsgBox Count




End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I appreciate it .. but unfortunately it is not what I want .. I need to use arrays only .. I didn't need to deal with sheets values at this point  .. see the notes in the main post to understand me more

Comment: But the "sheets values" you mention are just reading in the data. If you need you can collapse v and v1 into a single array. The procedure will be the same.

Comment: dear @volcompt , I try your code in separate workbook with the data in the image , it always show the message "0" only , is that true for this data ? .. I need to sum six values from round 0  with one value from round 1 , the result (427) is divided by 7 .. ( round 0 and 1 are in one big 2D array ) so **my question is** : Is there a way to sum values from different columns (rounds) in multi-dimensional array??

Comment: I try the code again in separate workbook with the data in the main post , it always show the message "7" only, is that true ? unfortunately I don't need this .. I need two for loop to look up in the 2D array and extract the value (427) ..

Comment: there is an example file in the main post

Comment: see the UPDATE in the main post

Answer (score 0):

It may help tremendously if you can give more detail about *what* problem you're trying to solve, instead of focusing on *how* to solve it this way. There is a possibility that there's another way of doing it that hasn't occurred to you that will be much simpler.

This isn't an answer. Yet. But it will take more space than is allowed in a comment to ensure we've got this right.

For your sample data:

```
round 0   round 1
9         28
65        84
28        47
84        103
41        60
66        85
115       134
```

You want to:

1. Sum all the values in Round 0 (9 + 65 + 28 + 84 + 41 + 66 + 115) = 408
2. Take that sum (408) mod 7 and see if the result is 0

   1. 408 / 7 = 58.28, so (408 mod 7) <> 0
3. If the result isn't 0 (as in this case)

   - Start substituting numbers from round 1 for numbers in Round 0

     1. Sum (28 + 65 + 28 + 84 + 41 + 66 + 115) = 427
     2. 427 / 7 = 61 (427 mod 7) = 0
     3. This is now your valid result set.
   - Had the first number in Round 1 been 29

     1. Sum (29 + 65 + 28 + 84 + 41 + 66 + 115) = 428
     2. 428 / 7 = 61.14 so (428 mod 7) <> 0
     3. Substitute the next number from round 1 for the next number from round 0
     4. Sum (9 + 84 + 28 + 84 + 41 + 66 + 115) = 427
     5. This is now your valid result set.
   - Is that the logic you're after?
   - What happens if you get to the end of round 1 and you don't find a total that (mod 7 = 0)?

Comment: dear FreeMan this is a Geophysics issue for one of my clients and he unfortunately didn't explain so much facts about the project and leave it :( .. and now I do this as a challenge :) ..

Comment: Yes that the logic I look after .. Did you try the code I wrote in the UPDATE section in the main post ?